# How to call contract function from already deployed contract in Ethereum

Tags: ethereum

I have an anready deployed contract in Enthereum.
And I want to call function from it.

Now I can do that:

```
watch_addr.call(bytes4(sha3("register()")))
```

But only when function has no parameters.
With parameters I try this, but have no success:

```
watch_addr.call(bytes4(sha3("register("This text is hard codded")")))
```

I read this solution: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/2826/call-function-on-another-contract
But I can't do that, because first contract is already deployed and when I deploy second contract, I don't know source code of first.
So, that solution is not for me.

I need a command like this:

```
watch_addr.call(bytes4(sha3("register("This text is hard codded")")))
```

How I can call function with parameters from other contract?
Any ideas...

Answer (score 1):

```
watch_addr.call(bytes4(sha3("Bar(int256)")), 42);
```